# Multiple JPanel or JFrame with MVC

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have read a number of articles/explanations on implementing MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern with Java such as:

http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/structure/40mvc.html

[GUI not working after rewriting to MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-not-working-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979)

and have visited several few more (including those in SO).

I am clear on what was explained in those links. However how should we implement a MVC when we have several JPanels/JFrames? So let say I want to implement a program which may display several JFrames at the same time.

**Question**: Should we try to only have 3 classes (Model, View, Controller) despite having multiple JFrames or should we have a separate View class for each JFrame?

I am aware that we could use the observer pattern to let various Frames communicate.

---

As for this link from SO, there is only 1 solution which does not address my question above: [Java MVC multiple JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465358/java-mvc-multiple-jframe)

I am also aware of [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice). But let's assume I will be having multiple JFrames which may display at the same time. I am more concern how would it be implemented with MVC.

Answer (score 1):

> Should we try to only have three classes (Model, View, Controller) despite having multiple `JFrame`s or should we have a separate View class for each `JFrame`?

The pattern doesn't specify *only* three classes; it describes the [interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687871/230513) among three instances. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25556585/230513), the pattern may appear an arbitrary number of times in a Swing application. It is a design element, *not* a panacea. Any of the [*observer pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) implementations mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) would serve. If you have a [compelling reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961122/230513) for multiple `JFrame` instances, consider using *modeless* dialogs, each having an [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) delegate, to group related view components.

> Is it alright if I create more than one class which represents view, e.g. five classes which act as view?

Yes, a Swing application may include multiple views. Swing's [*separable model architecture*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html#separable) provides multiple view components, each of which listens to its own model and may serve as its own controller. For example, `JTable` is a view component that listens to its `TableModel`, but it *also* functions as a controller to handle editing within a cell. Moreover, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513) and [here](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net), more than one view may listen to a single model.

Comment: "The pattern doesn't specify only three classes" So is it alright if I create more than one class which represents view (for e.g. 5 classes which act as view)?